# PrototypeJS library compatible with Firefox Extensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, prototypejs

Does anyone know if there is a PrototypeJS library that is compatible with Firefox Extensions?  I have written a JS piece of code that is 700 line in Prototype and do not want to rehash it out using JQuery which I know is reccomended for XUL Extensions in Firefox?  I've heard of Prototype XUL, but it seems like it is essentially just "Prototype Lite" and not as extensive as its original file.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you include prototype as part of your Javascript?

Comment: followup question: If it's "incompatible", can you post a link that says something that suggests quirky behavior. It's not something I, or I imagine someone else would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems with prototype. The main reason is that there is a whole bunch of window checking happening. What I've ended up doing is removing anything that has to do with window and dom manipulation of prototypejs to create my own prototype-custom.js.

This file contains only javascript augmentation like Enumerable, Function.prototype additions ( bind, curry, etc )

This ought to do it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can be embedded in extension (Ubiquity, for example), so it *should* be possible with PrototypeJS!